# how long will an 11w bulb last on 3 x 500mAh 3.7v cells

Tags: voltage, batteries, watts

I have this question that I can't seem to figure out. I have an 11 Watt bulb and 3 500mAh 3.7V Lithium Polymer Cells. And the question is how long the bulb will last. Can anyone help me with the calculations?

Comment: The bulb or the batteries? Also what voltage the bulb is rated for?

Comment: How long would the bulb be lit so the batteries.

Comment: What is the voltage rating of the bulb?

Comment: I am not told, all I'm told is that it is an 11 Watt CFL energy saving light bulb.

Comment: If it's a CFL like you plug into a normal light socket it's unlikely to work when connected directly to batteries. Are you using an inverter?

Comment: It's just a question I got asked by my lecturer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at only power available and drain:
500mAh * 3 * 3.7V = 5.55 Watt Hours.
5.55 WH / 11w = .504 hours.